# wpf webbrowser on transparent window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF WebBrowser control in a Window.

I want to remove the default window controls so I set **AllowsTransparency="True"** and **WindowStyle="None"**.

```
<Window x:Class="InstallerToolkit.InteractiveDemosWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="870" Width="1110" WindowStyle="None"  AllowsTransparency="True"  WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid>
    <WebBrowser Name="WebBrowser" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="795" Margin="10,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1082" />    
</Grid>
```

This results in me not being able to see my webbrowser contents.  If I remove the AllowsTransparency="True" then I can see by webpage but I now have the default controls which I dont want.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Try adding `ResizeMode = NoResize`. I'm on the phone, I guess that's the property;

Comment: Nice! I struggle with WPF to create a custom window! It was worth it!

Answer (score 1):

If the functionality you are looking for is truly AllowTransparency, you can update to WPF 4.5 where they have added a fix to Airspace  issues, [read this](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/wpf-45-%E2%80%93-part-8-solving) for more details.

If you are unable to upgrade your version of WPF then you will need to disable resize as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `ResizeMode = NoResize` should get you rid of the controls. I should mention that `AllowTransparency = True` can reduce performance! Depending on the kind of software, try avoinding it!